# numpy array add value

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to add new value into a numpy array with the following example

```
dict_created = {"A": [0,0], "B": [0,0], "C": [0,0], "D": [0,0], 
                "E": [0,0], "F": [0,0], "G": [0,0]} 

res_array = np.array(list(dict_created.items()))
```

now, I want to add `"Q": [1,2]` into each item expect the result like:

```
{"AQ": [1,2], "BQ": [1,2], "CQ": [1,2], "DQ": [1,2], "EQ": [1,2], "FQ": [1,2], "GQ": [1,2]}
```

I have tried with + sign but returned as `[0, 0, 1, 2]` for the value of each item, rather than add up with given values.

what is the correct method to return the expected result?

Thanks you

Comment: Your `numpy.array` object is a strange dtype=object array. Why not just use a `list`? IOW, **why are you working with numpy at all?**

Comment: I don't quite understand why you expect Numpy to help here. Fundamentally, you are trying to create and then modify a dictionary. Numpy doesn't deal in those. You could use Numpy to represent and then update the *values* in that dict (which currently are lists, and could be Numpy arrays), but it's clearly overkill for lists that short.

Comment: Print `res_array` so both you and we have a clear idea what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to update both the key and values of a dictionary, this is what I thought (using `numpy` to add the lists instead of appending them):

```py
import numpy as np

new_key = "Q"
new_value = [1,2]

result = dict((k+new_key, np.add(v, new_value)) for k, v in dict_created.items())
```

Expected output:

```sh
{'AQ': array([1, 2]), 'BQ': array([1, 2]), 'CQ': array([1, 2]), 'DQ': array([1, 2]), 'EQ': array([1, 2]), 'FQ': array([1, 2]), 'GQ': array([1, 2])}
```

You can also do the following (alternative way using [dictionary comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html)):

```py
result = {k+new_key:np.add(v, new_value) for k, v in dict_created.items()}
```

### **Edit:**

According to your comment, the combination of keys and values would be in the order of billions. You shouldn't expect a fast solution even with *numpy*, but, in any case, Python [dicts](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/) are well optimized.

You can check more about performance on the following questions:

[Python dictionary vs list, which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927794/python-dictionary-vs-list-which-is-faster)

[Python lists/dictionaries vs. numpy arrays: performance vs. memory control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935892/python-lists-dictionaries-vs-numpy-arrays-performance-vs-memory-control)

[Why is this loop faster than a dictionary comprehension for creating a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542742/why-is-this-loop-faster-than-a-dictionary-comprehension-for-creating-a-dictionar)

**For the filtering and sorting examples I've modified the `dict_created` to this:**

```py
dict_created = {"A": [1,0], "B": [0,0], "C": [0,0], "D": [0,0], "E": [0,0], "F": [0,0], "G": [3,0]}
# Result
{'AQ': array([2, 2]), 'BQ': array([1, 2]), 'CQ': array([1, 2]), 'DQ': array([1, 2]), 'EQ': array([1, 2]), 'FQ': array([1, 2]), 'GQ': array([4, 2])}
```

#### Filtering

```py
# Filter elements with x > 1
filtered_dict = {k:v for k, v in result.items() if v[0] > 1}
# {'AQ': array([2, 2]), 'GQ': array([4, 2])}
```

#### Sorting

```py
# Sorts keys
sorted_keys = sorted(result)
# ['AQ', 'BQ', 'CQ', 'DQ', 'EQ', 'FQ', 'GQ']
```

```py
# Sorting by dict keys
sorted_with_kv = {k:v for k, v in sorted(result.items())}
# {'AQ': array([2, 2]), 'BQ': array([1, 2]), 'CQ': array([1, 2]), 'DQ': array([1, 2]), 'EQ': array([1, 2]), 'FQ': array([1, 2]), 'GQ': array([4, 2])}
```

```py
# Sorting by x given [x, y]
sorted_with_kv_lambda = {k:v for k, v in sorted(result.items(), key=lambda elem: elem[1][0])}
# {'BQ': array([1, 2]), 'CQ': array([1, 2]), 'DQ': array([1, 2]), 'EQ': array([1, 2]), 'FQ': array([1, 2]), 'AQ': array([2, 2]), 'GQ': array([4, 2])}
```

You should try to stick with *dictionary comprehension* since it yields the best performance when working with Python dictionaries.

For a more in-depth explanation, I recommend this reading: [How Do Dictionaries and Sets Work](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-python/9781449361747/ch04.html)

Comment: Thanks you. it works, just extent the question. for performance concern. the dict_created would be as huge as more than 100K, the new_key_value pair choice would be also another 10Kish... I am expecting to have the product of the combination of all of them then do some filtering and sorting. What would be the best approach for this circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [88]: dict_created = {"A": [0,0], "B": [0,0], "C": [0,0], "D": [0,0],
    ...:                 "E": [0,0], "F": [0,0], "G": [0,0]}
    ...: 
    ...: res_array = np.array(list(dict_created.items()))
<ipython-input-88-bc8f2c25c347>:4: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.

In [89]: res_array
Out[89]: 
array([['A', list([0, 0])],
       ['B', list([0, 0])],
       ['C', list([0, 0])],
       ['D', list([0, 0])],
       ['E', list([0, 0])],
       ['F', list([0, 0])],
       ['G', list([0, 0])]], dtype=object)
```

You have created an object dtype array containing letters and lists.

You weren't clear about the addition, but let's assume you did:

```
In [91]: res_array+list({"Q": [1,2]}.items())
<ipython-input-91-1bdaa5aac0d7>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.

Out[91]: 
array([['AQ', list([0, 0, 1, 2])],
       ['BQ', list([0, 0, 1, 2])],
       ['CQ', list([0, 0, 1, 2])],
       ['DQ', list([0, 0, 1, 2])],
       ['EQ', list([0, 0, 1, 2])],
       ['FQ', list([0, 0, 1, 2])],
       ['GQ', list([0, 0, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

The first column is strings, and the `+` is string concatenate.

The second is lists, which has a similar concatenate.

What you want array addition for the second column.

Let's turn that column into arrays:

```
In [93]: res_array[:,1]=[np.array(i) for i in res_array[:,1]]
In [94]: 
In [94]: res_array
Out[94]: 
array([['A', array([0, 0])],
       ['B', array([0, 0])],
       ['C', array([0, 0])],
       ['D', array([0, 0])],
       ['E', array([0, 0])],
       ['F', array([0, 0])],
       ['G', array([0, 0])]], dtype=object)
In [95]: 
In [95]: res_array+list({"Q": np.array([1,2])}.items())
<ipython-input-95-2703d0356b14>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.

Out[95]: 
array([['AQ', array([1, 2])],
       ['BQ', array([1, 2])],
       ['CQ', array([1, 2])],
       ['DQ', array([1, 2])],
       ['EQ', array([1, 2])],
       ['FQ', array([1, 2])],
       ['GQ', array([1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

I'm leaving the 'ragged array' warning that np version 1.19 started adding.  You should be aware that you are creating a non-standard `numpy` array, and treat it appropriately.  Making a numpy array from a `dict`, especially if you want both keys and values is a bit odd.  `numpy` is best for arrays with uniform dtype - all character or all numbers.  This mixed stuff is awkward.

Here is a non-numpy way of making a new dict:

```
In [97]: newdict= {key+'Q': [i+j for i,j in zip(value,[1,2])] for key, value in dict_created.items()}

In [98]: newdict
Out[98]: 
{'AQ': [1, 2],
 'BQ': [1, 2],
 'CQ': [1, 2],
 'DQ': [1, 2],
 'EQ': [1, 2],
 'FQ': [1, 2],
 'GQ': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this method:

```py
new_item = {"Q":[1,2]}
new_item = np.array(list(new_item.items()))
res_array = np.concatenate((res_array, new_item))
```

Comment: @user4603876 So sorry, I made a mistake while changin name from my sketch code. Try now.